# would like to suppress the output of pkill on a background process

Tags: shell-script, background-process, pkill

I have a shell-script in which I do an

```
iostat -c 1  > data.cpu. &
```

Later in the script, after I've collected the data I'm interested in, I do a

```
pkill iostat
```

which kills iostat and allows me to continue by processing data.cpu and generating a report written to stdout. Part of the report includes

```
[1]+  Terminated              iostat -c 1  > data.cpu
```

produced by the pkill.  For aesthetic reasons I would like to prevent the "Terminated" message from appearing. I tried various redirects, but so far I haven't succeeded.

Is there any way to prevent this part of the output?

Comment: [How to suppress Terminated message after killing in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81520) may be helpful

Comment: That output is not produced by pkill, but by the shell. Start from incorrect assumptions, reach wrong conclusions (No, disown doesn't change a process "from a background to a foreground process").

Answer (score 2):

@[Quasímodo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/388654/quas%C3%ADmodo) suggested I look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/81520 which I did not find helpful. However, one of the suggestions in that post pointed to https://stackoverflow.com/q/5719030/1997354

which used `disown` ([man page](https://helpmanual.io/builtin/disown/)) to exactly solve my problem. Namely:

```
iostat -c 1 > data.cpu &
disown
# collect required data
pkill iostat
```

In addition to using disown there is a way to suppresses the "*Terminated*" message without using disown -- namely use kill instead of pkill, as in the following

```
iostat -c 1 > data.cpu &
iostat_pid=$(pidof)
# collect required data
kill -9 $iostat_pid
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the answer to the question you linked, the displaying of such messages as those can be controlled at a `wait` command.

So one approach might be to run `iostat` in background and immediately `wait` for it with a redirected stderr, and run such entire compound command again in the background so as not to wait on `wait`.

That is:

```
(iostat -c 1 > data.cpu & wait 2>/dev/null) &
```

After that, you can `pkill iostat` as you were doing originally.

Be careful in fact to target precisely that `iostat` process, and not the shell’s sub-process being that `iostat`’s parent. A `pkill iostat` kills all `iostat` processes currently running, so that suffices.